# Ruby on Rails Postgres remote database connection using Socks Proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, activerecord

I have a remote database accessible only to whitelisted IPs. I have verified that it can be connected by using my quotaguard static ips. But, with the quotaguard setup in my ruby on rails app, its not working. My app is hosted on heroku server and I am using puma not unicorn. Has anyone ever been able to get this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I contacted the quotaguard support and got my problem solved. My mistake was in the port number. I used qgtunnel setup with following instructions given by support agent. They worked like magic. Also, rails console opened by heroku run did not still use the proxy settings but the main app is working perfectly now. Here are the steps given:

1. Download the QGTunnel into the root of your project
   curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/quotaguard/qgtunnel-latest.tar.gz | tar xz
2. Setup a tunnel in the quotaguard dashboard
   heroku addons:open quotaguardstatic
   This will open our dashboard.
   At the top right, click Settings, then Setup.
   Then on the left, click Tunnel, then Create Tunnel.
   Remote Destination: tcp://:5432
   Local Port: 5433
   Transparent Mode: true
   Encryption: false (I believe the postgres protocol is already encrypted, but you should double check)

NOTE: I used local port 5433, because 5432 (postgres default) is likely already in use by your production database.  If not, then you can use 5432.

3. Update your procfile

   `web: bin/qgtunnel bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
4. Update your config/database.yml to point to the right port
   If you used 5433 on step 2, then you need to change your connection to point to that.

   `external:
     adapter: postgresql
     encoding: unicode
     pool: 5
     host: remote_database_host
     database: remote_database_name
     username: remote_database_username
     password: remote_database_password`
5. Push your changes to heroku and bask in the tunneling glory.

Comment: I should also add if you're using transparent mode you need to have `vendor/nss_wrapper` s well which comes in the zip